# Android two integers with same value not equating properly

Tags: java, android, integer

I'm in not a java guy, so I'm not sure if this is just a language issue.

I am writing an Android app.  At one point in the app I compare to intgers (version #) to see what version of the app they are using, to perform some action if they are not up to date.  I notice that my action code is always being run.  So I checked with a debugger and where I check to see if they are running the correct version, I have code like this:

```
if (savedVersionCode != currentVersionCode){
   //perform work
}
```

both `savedVersionCode` and `currentVersionCode` are Integers and are equal to the same value (226 in this case),  but it still jumps in and performs the work.

I do notice that although that values are both 226,  each integer (if you inspect it in eclipse) have an `id`  and they are both different.

Any ideas on whats going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they're `Integer` values, you're comparing the references. Two different objects can effectively represent the same number. Try:

```
if (savedVersionCode.intValue() != currentVersionCode.intValue())
```

or

```
if (!savedVersionCode.equals(currentVersionCode))
```

Note that you may well have managed with lower numbers, as autoboxing will return the same references for numbers in a small range around 0. So for example:

```
Integer x = 5;
Integer y = 5;
System.out.println(x == y); // Prints true

x = 1000;
y = 1000;
System.out.println(x == y); // *Could* print true, but probably won't
```

Comment: in Integer the range is -127 up to at least 128 inclusive and the high bound can be set with `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>` option