# Invalid login id even if I am inserting the right credentials

Tags: android

I designed a login form in android which takes employee id (an integer value) and a password. But even if I enter the exact credentials it doesn't move to the next activity. It also prints the correct empid in logcat. But always the last Toast message is shown.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    empId_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emp_id);
    password_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            empid = Integer.parseInt(empId_edt.getText().toString().trim());
            System.out.println(empid);

            password = password_edt.getText().toString().trim();
            if(empid != null && empid>=10000 && empid<=10130)
            {
                if(password != null && password.length() > 0)
                {
                    if(empid == 10001 && password == "hrms")
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter valid Employee Id & Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter a valid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please enter a valid Employee Id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you able to compare empid to `null`. your code says its a int. Integers can not be compared with `null`.

Comment: `if(empid != null && empid>=10000 && empid<=10130)` in this line. First empid must be referring to some other String and that String might be null.

Comment: @KalpeshPatel how can empid be "some other string" if the code clearly shows it's an integer initialized right there.

Comment: @VipulKumar I said first empid in the if statement must be String. If its a integer then this code will not compile.

Comment: But `Integer.parseInt()` would throw an exception if that was a String. way before going into if condition.

Comment: Your point is also correct. I assumed A.R. has posted only partial code. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use password.equals("hrms") instead password=="hrms".

A string can not be compared with "=" symbol. You need to use built in methods for equality checks for String

Answer (score 1):

The variable `empid` **should be** an integer. You can't check it for null (you can check it for 0). Instead, you can check `empId_edt.getText()` for null (you should do it before parsing to integer). And yeah, You should put a `try-catch` around `Integer.parseInt()`. and compare strings with `.equals()` rather than `==`. These things should fix your code. Thanks to comment and another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This gives answer of your question **The JVM is caching Integer values. == only works for numbers between -128 and 127 **

**So use if (empid.intValue() == 10001)**

[Android two integers with same value not equating properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896603/android-two-integers-with-same-value-not-equating-properly)